# Not Using an Anonymous Function w/ Jquery Events

Tags: javascript, click, jquery, anonymous-function

In my program, I have a click event that does the same thing for many buttons, except the class in a small part of the event handler function is different for each one.  Right now, I'm just using an anonymous function for this.  The function attached to this event is pretty long, and I anticipate there being many buttons ( maybe 60 or so? ). I could copy and paste the currently working function I have 60 times, but that will make my javascript file huge.

What I would like to do, is define the event handler function outside of the on() function, so I can just say `$('#some_button').on('click', my_event_handler("my_arg") );`
This will really simplify my code.

I made a js fiddle that kind of gives a very small example of what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/AsmmF/

The only problem, is that I can't get it to work!

I'm going to go see Ted, and try out your solutions to my problem when I get back.

Thanks much for any help that you can provide me!

Comment: "your solutions to my problem"...isn't the internet great? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#some_button').on('click', my_event_handler("my_arg") )
```

Should be:

```
$('#some_button').on('click', null, "my_arg", my_event_handler);
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AsmmF/7/)

Comment: The OP understands that, however they were asking how to make a call such as the above (knowing it wouldn't work as intended).

Comment: @BradChristie. Read it again.

Comment: Inserting data in the event is interesting nonetheless, but will require OP to access the parameters differently (or at least re-assign the var names in the beginning of the function). +1 for the "innovativeness". `:P`

Answer (score 5):

You just need to wrap your function call in an anonymous function.

`$('#some_button').on('click', function() {my_event_handler("my_arg");} );`

Comment: +1 for the fastest gun in the West, and here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/AsmmF/3/).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté. I updated your DEMO, showing an alternative way.

Comment: @gdoron No problem, my fiddle was basically OP's fiddle with a couple fixes to make it work. You're one of the few that managed to find the usefulness of the 3rd parameter for the `.on` method, nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

Make your function return a function.

```
function button_click(some_var) {
    return function() {
        $('#button').after('<p>This is being attached: ' + some_var + '</p>');
    };
};
$('#button').on('click', button_click("hello") );
```

(Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/63Le2/)

Comment: Albeit the strange construct which I have no idea how it doesn't trigger in the handler declaration, it works seamlessly. +1